# socket.getaddrinfo keeps returning OSError: -2

Tags: sockets, micropython

i'm trying to run a socket on my esp8266 but keep getting `OSError: -2`.
I tried:

```
>>> addr = socket.getaddrinfo('smart-socket-bdcc5.firebaseio.com', 443)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: -2
```

and

```
>>> addr = socket.getaddrinfo('smart-socket-bdcc5.firebaseio.com', 80)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: -2
```

When I execute it in usual python command line it works ok.
Also I tried `usocket` instead of `socket` - hasn't helped.

Answer (score 2):

The reason was simple: wrong wifi creds